# Xcode: Pdf's in a UIScrollView with Paging enabled

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, ipad

Im having trouble loading pdf's in a `UIWebView` when inside a `Scrollview` with paging enabled and just can't get my head around it.

So i started with the paging sample code available at apple developer, once done that i loaded instead of a Label in the `ViewController` a `UIWebView` that loads the Pdf. and it did worked but with a lot of bugs with rotation and scaling on the device.

On iOS 5 scaling is simply not working it zooms but scrolls to top and doesn't allow me to move inside the `UIWebView` so when I move the only thing i do is move between the pages not inside the `UIWebView`. 
And with iOS 4 it does let me move but has tons of trouble when rotating the device, it doesn't refresh the `UIWebView` inside to the new frame (even though i do change the frame on `didRotate method`), so i was wondering if there is another method to load the PDFs that is not a `UIWebView` that is compatible with zooming and rotating with the `UIScrollView` with Paging.

Or is there something I should consider when loading the `UIWebView` inside the `UIScrollView`? a feature i have to enable or something i am missing?

Because at the beginning I thought it was a bug on iOS 5 and that i was doing something wrong when rotating (which probably i am anyway) but i have several apps on my iPad with ios 5 that do the same but have absolutely no trouble.

I hope you can point me in the right direction.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should really be using [CATiledLayer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CATiledLayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html) and [CGPDFDocument](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/Reference/CGPDFDocument/Reference/reference.html) for this kind of stuff.

There is an example that I found just now : [Olive Toast's Blog](http://www.olivetoast.com/blog/hamish/simple_uiscrollview_catiledlayer_example.ot)

Its time consuming to wrap your head around these concepts, but its well worth it. I created a webView+scrollview combo for a pdf reader, which had to be junked and rewritten with CATiledLayer.

Doing it using webview in scrollview gobbles up a lot of resources, ending in a very bad UX

Edit: Apparently there is another post that has a [better answer than mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6588003/pdf-view-with-horizontal-scroll) (you may find this link useful)

Comment: Let me review your example and the other post, I do believe `CATiledLayer` and `CGPDF` is the correct way but I hope your example is able to point me on the right direction to at least be able to start coding for this. And if so will mark your answer as the right one. Tons of thanks!

Comment: the URL you gave is disabled but i was able to get the example from the cached site from google.

Comment: edited to take care of that! Thanks for accepting the answer! Glad I could help.