# PDF view horizontally

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PDF View with horizontal scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6588003/pdf-view-with-horizontal-scroll)

I want to view my PDF files. I'm using a webview and it's working fine. But I got a problem. I need to swipe the PDF pages horizontally. But it can only be viewed vertically. Can it be swiped horizontally? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: for ePub , you may find here http://code.google.com/p/epub-tools/source/browse/#svn/trunk/epubtools/epubjs