# Split Pdf into pages for displaying on UIPageViewController

Tags: iphone, ipad, uipageviewcontroller

I have a PDF document that comes from server and i would want it to display it upon the UIPageViewController on iPad in order to give it a nice page curling effect .The Only way I could think of is to split the PDF into pages and then use each page as a separate view controller.Do any one know how could i do that?.What do you recommend ,splitting pdf into a set of pdfs or a pngs.I am not afraid with CGPdfPageRef so I might not use UIWebview.
Thanks

Comment: if you are interested in horizontal page pdf view then http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6588003/pdf-view-with-horizontal-scroll I am not sure if we can add page curl effect

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your idea is absolutely correct.

UIPageViewController can work with a datasource (just like a table view controller).
It takes a UIViewController object as each page.

So the idea is, page view controller's datasource creates CGPDFDocumentRef from your pdf file path/url, fetches each page `CGPDFDocumentGetPage(pdfDocRef, pageNumber)` creates a view controller object which can render this page and returns it via datasource methods.

You'll get a lot of documentation/code to help you with rendering a CGPDFPageRef in your view. Its pretty easy.

Answer (score 5):

I have made a project that shows each page of a PDF file in a UIPageViewController, using the methods described by lukya. You can download the source code from GitHub [here](https://github.com/jackhumphries/UIPageViewController-PDF).

Comment: hey why you deleted your project?